# How do I scrape for links to webpages which gets opened in another tab on clicking an HTML element using Scrapy and Playwright?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I want to scrape this link : https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Mumbai for the links for each property.

The link to the individual pages for each property is not in the HTML source code. The opening of the page instead is linked to an event. How do I get the links to the page that opens using Scrapy and Playwright?

Comment: please share your existing code

Comment: I don't have coded anything yet since i have no idea how I would go about doing that

Comment: It's always important to do some research and ask a question with facts and serious code. Asking for a whole tutorial wouldn't be more helpful. Anyway, check my answer for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Each website is different and needs to be treated differently. Usually the journey starts from the element panel of the page.

[image]

Upon taking a closer look at the elements panel of the url you have shared, we can see each card is inside a div and the div also has a script tag with a json. The json indeed has the URL you were looking for.

Here is the code to extract the URLs that you can run inside the [page.evaluate function](https://playwright.dev/docs/evaluating).

```js
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  const urls = [];

  // parent card elements
  var cardElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class="mb-srp__list"]')];
  for(let cardElement of cardElements) {
    // get nested script tag inside each card element that contains the url
    const script = cardElement.querySelector('script'); 

    // but the content of the tag is a string, so we need to parse
    const cardJSON = JSON.parse(script.innerHTML); 

    // finally save whatever data we want
    urls.push(cardJSON.url);
  }
  return urls;
});
```

Here is a shorter version of the code that can go inside page.evaluate,

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('[class="mb-srp__list"]')].map(card=>JSON.parse(card.querySelector('script').innerHTML).url)
```